# how can i setting up jvm heap size in jetty6.1.24

Tags: jetty, out-of-memory, permgen

I am using jetty6.1.26, and I deploy an web application at webapps folder directly. Because my application have lot of jars, so when jetty startup

```
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

I am also using tomcat6, and just put the blew line at the first line of catline.sh ,that will be ok.

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -server -XX:PermSize=64M -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m"
```

now, how can I setting up java opts in jetty? Thanks in advance.

Ps: I modified jetty-service.conf, and update 
     wrapper.java.maxmemory=1024
   it still not working. Anyone who has good ideas ,thanks

Answer (score 3):

How do you launch jetty?

If you are on Ubuntu and installed jetty with apt-get you should have a file /etc/default/jetty where you can edit JAVA_OPTIONS

Comment: This file does not exist in my Ubuntu installation. [I use jetty, so it is installed]

Comment: The jetty packages from ubuntu 10.04 and 12.04 have that file. Which Ubuntu are you running? And did you install jetty from the standard Ubuntu repositories?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04, maybe I installed it by hand (it was quite a long time ago).